# Type {} is not assignable to type intrinsic attributes and props React + TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on a project to practice with React + TS, and I am having the following error:

```
Type '{key: string, footballShirts: ItemInfoEntity} is not assignable to type 'IntrisicAttributes&Props. Property 'footballShirt' does not exist on type 'Intrinsic Attributes & Props'.
```

Well, I have been researching in Stack Overflow and Google, and all the solutions I have found tell you about using an interface, but I am already using it. Here my interface:

```
export interface ItemInfoEntity {
    id: string;
    picURL: string;
    title: string;
}
```

Here the code of the father component:

```
export const FootballShirtsPage: React.FC = () => {

    const [footballShirts, setFootballShirts] = useState<ItemInfoEntity[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getFootballShirts()
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                setFootballShirts(data);
            }
            );
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <Link to="/" className="navbar">Football Shirts</Link>
            <Link to="/videogames" className="navbar">Videogames</Link>
            <h2>Hello from Football Shirts Page</h2>
            <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }}>
                <CardContent>
                    {footballShirts.map((footballShirt) => (
                        <ItemInfo key={footballShirt.id} footballShirt={footballShirt} /> //ERROR: Type '{key: string, footballShirts: ItemInfoEntity} is not assignable to type 'IntrisicAttributes&Props. Property 'footballShirt' does not exist on type 'Intrinsic Attributes & Props'
                    ))}
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </>
    );
};
```

And here the code of `ItemInfo`:

```
import React from "react";

import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia/CardMedia";

import { ItemInfoEntity } from "../model/model";

interface Props {
    item: ItemInfoEntity;
}

export const ItemInfo: React.FC<Props> = (props:Props) => {

    const { item } = props;

    return (
        <div key={item.id}>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I dont know where the mistake is, since I am using an interface in the children component. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you put [] after ItemInfoEntity in the interface Props

Comment: You are right, I thought I was receiving an array of objects but I am receiving an object though. Without that, the second error disappear, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to match the names of your props. You are passing attribute named **footballShirt** to your *ItemInfo* component, but in your *ItemInfo* component, you have defined an attribute named **item** in your *Props*.

Hope this helps :).